# Java8 code stop compiling and make me to do an unnecessary explicit casting

Tags: java, eclipse, java-8, type-inference, eclipse-neon

I have recently updated to the Eclipse Neon and my existing code stop to compile. It seem to be that the compiler can not do the type inference, and make me to do an unnecessary explicit casting. 
I have this example code:

```
public class ProductManager {

    //Mocked: originaly a Bean
    com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListeningExecutorService executor;

    public Stream<Result<Product, ItineraryDTO>> getItineraries(Set<Product> productsSet) {
        // Asynchronously get itinerary for every flight
        Stream<ListenableFuture<Result<Product, ItineraryDTO>>> futures =
            productsSet.stream().map(Result.asyncCall(product ->
                    this.executor.submit(() -> this.getItinerary(product)
                )));

        // Wait and get results for every submitted task
        Stream<Result<Product, ItineraryDTO>> results = Result.waitAndGet(futures);
        return results;
    }

    private ItineraryDTO getItinerary(Product flight) {
        // Mocked: originaly get itinerary from a REST service
        return new ItineraryDTO();
    }
    }
```

The `asyncCall` method has this signature:

```
public static <T, U> Function<T, ListenableFuture<Result<T, U>>> asyncCall(
            Function<T, ListenableFuture<U>> asyncMethod);
```

Eclipse suggest that i have to cast the resulting stream. Is this an Eclipse bug or am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Assuming you are using the same compiler, it shouldn't make any difference. Try compiling from the command line with `javac`

Comment: It would help if you could reduce this to a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was [a bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/496942) introduced in Eclipse Mars (4.5) (see [bug 496942 comment 8](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=496942#c8) for a reproducing example). It has meanwhile been fixed (as of milestone 1 towards Eclipse Oxygen (4.7)). The fix can be tested using [this integration build](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops4/I20160629-0800/#EclipseSDK).

Comment: FWIW, the change that caused this regression in Eclipse was driven by adopting a late change in JLS (via https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8038747 resolved Feb.2015).

Comment: Thank you! I reported the bug!